# Async Socket reading multiple messages as one

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

In my "client" i have the following piece of code:

```
socket.Send(ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Test0"), SocketFlags.None);
socket.Send(ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Test1"), SocketFlags.None);
socket.Send(ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Test2"), SocketFlags.None);
```

In my "server" i have the following:

```
public void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
     StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
     Socket handler = state.WorkSocket;

     int read = handler.EndReceive(ar);

     if (read > 0)
     {
        string aux = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, read);
        //Rest of the code...
```

My problem is: aux is "Test0Test1Test2"... I was expecting that my ReadCallback would be called 3 times, one for each `send`... but its being called only once... what do i have to do to make the readcallback behave as i expected?

Comment: What type of socket are you using? A TCP socket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using a TCPclient socket type and had this problem. It has to do with the [Nagle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm). I was able to solve the problem by setting the NoDelay property to true, which allows the data to be sent immediately even if the buffer is not yet full.

Edit: After reading the question again, I am not sure you have the same problem that I did. I was sending commands to a device then reading response data. Is this what you are trying to do, or are you trying to see what was sent?

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be using a stream-type socket (e.g. TCP as opposed to UDP).

Stream sockets are streams - the receiver can't necessarily tell whether the message was sent with multiple sends or in a single send.

If you need messages to be separated you need to either use a packet-oriented or message-oriented protocol or implement your own method of showing where messages begin and end.

Comment: I'm using SocketType.Stream indeed... which should i use then? DGram? Reading the description i think i should use "Seqpacket" but it throws a exception...

Answer (score 5):

I'll just echo what Ben said, and try to add a tiny bit of additional info. I ran into the same situation 5-6 years ago, and did as much reasearch as I could, and concluded that "that's the way it is". Here's the only "reference" I have that more-or-less confirms that:

http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/archive/index.php/t-204348.html

So what I did was prefix each packet with the length of the packet, and "parse" the received packets at the other end.